# CKEDITOR - AJUDA!

Tags: php, javascript

Estou aprendendo PHP e estou tentando incluir o CKeditor em uma modal na qual as informações vem através do javascript, porém o CKeditor não aplica no textarea que vem do javascript, não exibe error nem nada. E nos outros textarea que não vem do javascript ele aplica normalmente.

**Botão que aciona a modal**

```
<div class='btnEditNoticia view_data_edit' id='1'><a href='#'><i class='far fa-edit'></i></a></div>
```

**Javascript que trás as informações da modal**

```
//visualizar informações para editar
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.view_data_edit', function(){
            var noticia_id = $(this).attr("id");
            if(noticia_id !== ''){
                var dados = {
                    noticia_id: noticia_id
                };
                $.post('/editar/vis_edit_noticia.php', dados, function(retorna){
                            //Carregar o conteúdo para o usuário
                            $("#visul_noticia").html(retorna);
                            $('#ModalEditarNoticia').modal('show'); 
                        });
            }
        })

    });
```

**Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalEditarNoticia" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalEditarNoticia" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="EditarNoticia">Editar Notícia</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form method="POST" action="/editar/edit_noticia" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <span id="visul_noticia"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            <input type="submit" name="btnEditNoticia" class="btn btn-danger" value="Editar">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Página que contém os dados da modal**

```
$resultado_noticia = '';
    
    $query_noticia = "SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias WHERE id = '" . $_POST['noticia_id'] . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result_noticia = mysqli_query($conn, $query_noticia);
    $row_noticia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_noticia);
    
    $resultado_noticia .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<label for="noticia" class="control-label">Título</label>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<input type="text" name="tituloNoticia" class="form-control" id="tituloNoticia" value="'.$row_noticia['titulo'].'">';
    $resultado_noticia .= '</div>';

    $result_categoria = "SELECT * FROM tbl_categorias_noticias ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $resultado_categoria = mysqli_query($conn, $result_categoria);

    $resultado_noticia .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<label for="categoria_noticia" class="control-label">Categoria</label>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<select class="form-control" name="categoria_noticia_id" id="categoria_noticia_id">';
    while ($row_categoria_n = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_categoria)) {
        //verifica se possui a variavel categoria id e associa ela ao id da categoria para ficar selecionado quando o úsuario for editar
        if (($row_noticia['categoria_id']) AND ($row_noticia['categoria_id'] == $row_categoria_n['id'])) {
            $resultado_noticia .= "<option value='".$row_categoria_n['id']."' selected>".$row_categoria_n['nome']."</option>";
        //caso não venha a informação da variavel aparece as opções
        }else{
            $resultado_noticia .= "<option value='".$row_categoria_n['id']."'>".$row_categoria_n['nome']."</option>";
        }
    }   
    $resultado_noticia .='</select>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '</div>';


    $result_tp_noticia = "SELECT * FROM tbl_tipo_ident ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $resultado_tp_noticia = mysqli_query($conn, $result_tp_noticia);

    $resultado_noticia .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<label for="categoria_noticia" class="control-label">Tipo</label>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<select class="form-control" name="tipo_noticia_id" id="tipo_noticia_id">';
    while ($row_tp_noticia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_tp_noticia)) {
        //verifica se possui a variavel categoria id e associa ela ao id da categoria para ficar selecionado quando o úsuario for editar
        if (($row_noticia['tipo_noticia_id']) AND ($row_noticia['tipo_noticia_id'] == $row_tp_noticia['id'])) {
            $resultado_noticia .= "<option value='".$row_tp_noticia['id']."' selected>".utf8_encode($row_tp_noticia['nome'])."</option>";
        //caso não venha a informação da variavel aparece as opções
        }else{
            $resultado_noticia .= "<option value='".$row_tp_noticia['id']."'>".utf8_encode($row_tp_noticia['nome'])."</option>";
        }
    }   
    $resultado_noticia .='</select>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '</div>';
    
    $resultado_noticia .= '<div class="form-group">';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<label for="noticia" class="control-label">Notícia</label>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<textarea class="form-control" name="textoEdit" id="textoEdit" rows="15" maxlength="2000">';
    $resultado_noticia .= $row_noticia['texto'];
    $resultado_noticia .= '</textarea>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '<span class="caracteres">2000</span> caracteres Restantes <br>';
    $resultado_noticia .= '</div>';

    $resultado_noticia .= '<input name="noticia_id" type="hidden" class="form-control" id="noticia_id" value="'.$row_noticia['id'].'">';

    
    echo $resultado_noticia;
```

**JavaScript CKEditor**

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/27.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
//editor de text area CKEDITOR
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#textoEdit' ), {
        toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'undo', 'redo', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList' ],
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prezado,

Considerando o que você descreveu, creio que a inicialização do CKEditor está ocorrendo anteriormente ao carregamento dos dados. Ou seja, quando você tenta inicializar, esse elemento não existe (pois, ainda será carregado via AJAX).

Para resolver, você precisa colocar a inicialização do CKEditor após a busca no banco de dados. Considerando o seu código, tente o seguinte:

```js
//visualizar informações para editar
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.view_data_edit', function(){
            var noticia_id = $(this).attr("id");
            if(noticia_id !== ''){
                var dados = {
                    noticia_id: noticia_id
                };
                $.post('/editar/vis_edit_noticia.php', dados, function(retorna){
                            //Carregar o conteúdo para o usuário
                            $("#visul_noticia").html(retorna);
                            //aqui já existem os dados e elementos buscados, portanto...
                            // ... é possível chamar o CKEditor
                            // IMPORTANTE: Lembre-se de corrigir o seletor abaixo ('#textoEdit') para o elemento adequado
                            ClassicEditor
                                .create( document.querySelector( '#textoEdit' ), {
                                    toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'undo', 'redo',                                                                                     'numberedList', 'bulletedList' ],
                                } )
                                .catch( error => {
                                    console.log( error );
    } );
                            $('#ModalEditarNoticia').modal('show'); 
                        });
            }
        })

    });
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcos, era exatamente isso!

Comment: Disponha. Estamos aqui para isso.